# ZIP and CSV file upload issue in Jmeter script which is recorded using Blazemeter

Tags: file-upload, jmeter, zip, mime-types, blazemeter

I have recorded a transaction using Blazemeter and trying to validate the same .jmx file in Jmeter 4.0. I have given the correct File path(jmeter/bin folder path) in Files Upload tab and below MIME Types but I am getting below error.

Please suggest.
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the majority of cases you need to tick `Use multipart/form-data for POST` box in order to be able to upload the files using JMeter:

[image]

See [RFC 2388 for more details](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2388). If you tick this box you need to remove [Content-Type](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Content-Type) header declaration from the [HTTP Header Manager](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#HTTP_Header_Manager)

Also be aware that [according to JMeter Best Practices you should be always using the latest version of JMeter](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/best-practices.html#use_latest_version) so consider upgrading to [JMeter 5.3](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/whats-new-in-jmeter-5.3/) (or whatever is the latest [JMeter stable version](https://jmeter.apache.org/download_jmeter.cgi))

And last but not the least, you should be able to normally record file upload requests using JMeter's [HTTP(S) Test Script Recorder](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#HTTP(S)_Test_Script_Recorder), just **make sure to copy the file(s) you will be uploading to JMeter's "bin" folder**

Comment: Hi @Dmitri T ...I have kept the input files in Jmeter/bin folder.Also implemented your suggestion to tick Multi-part check box and remove Content-Type from HTTP header manager.But I am getting 500 Response Code and in the Response Data tab I am getting NullPointerException

Comment: Hi @Dmitri T I have implemented the suggesstions you have shared but still getting 500-Internal Server Error in that request.My doubt is whether I am giving proper MIME Type for .zip,.csv and jpg.Please suggest if any other changes I need to do.